# Cassandra read latency increases while writing

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a cassandra cluster, its read latency increases during writes. The writes mostly happen via spark jobs during the night time. The writes happen in huge bursts, is there a way to reduce read latency during the writes. The writes happen using LOCAL_QUORUM and reads happen using LOCAL_ONE. Is there a way to reduce read latency when writes are happening?

Cassandra Cluster Configs

10 Node cassandra cluster (5 in DC1, 5 in DC2)

CPU: 8 Core

Memory: 32GB

Grafana Metrics

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give some advice:

1. Use [LCS](https://www.instaclustr.com/apache-cassandra-compaction/#:%7E:text=This%20compaction%20strategy%20triggers%20a,insert%2Dheavy%20and%20general%20workloads) compaction strategy.
2. Prefer [round-robin](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/RoundRobinPolicy.html) load balancing policy for reads.
3. Choose **partition_key** wisely so that requests are not bombarded on a single partition.

> Partition size also play a good role. Cassandra recommends to have smaller partition size. However, I have tested with Partitions of 10000 rows each with each row having size of 800 bytes. It worked better than with 3000 rows(or even 1 row). Very tiny partitions tend to increase CPU usage when data stored is large in terms of row count. However, very large partitions should be avoided even.

4. **Replication Factor** should be chosen strategically . Write consistency level should be decided considering the replication of all keyspaces.